# DbSet.Local is raising Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

with the following code I raise the `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` exception.

I'm trying to insert one or more `MasterEntity` in the context.

```cs
public class MasterEntity {
    public Entity E {get; set;}
}
```

In the process I want tho create the non existing Entity.

So to check if a given Entity exists: I try to retreive it from the database. If it does not exist then I `Add` it.

Both operations upate the DbContext and the Local view (by loading or adding).

The Local view should give me a view of the "context state".

the question is: why is the exception raised ?

```cs
public class Ctrl : ApiControler {
    Repo _repo;

    public Ctrl(Repo repo) {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MasterEntityEntityUpSert(IEnumerable<Model> CollectionOfModels) {
        // the _repo is instanciated by the DI
        foreach (ModelType m in CollectionOfModels ) {
            //START of the loop on Local
            Entity e = _repo.GetByCache(x => x.Id == m.id); // SECOND ITERATION raises said exception
                                                            //an entity was added in the previous one
            //END of the loop on Local

            if ( e == null ) {
                //that is if Local does not contain a retreived or added Entity
                e = new Entity {
                    Id = m.id
                }
            }
            // ...
            MasterEntity me = new MasterEntity {
                E = e
            }
            //START of the modification of Local
            _repo.Insert(me);  // here  _ctx.Set<Entity>().Local is modified
                               //but it is outside the loop from GetByCache
            //END of the modification of Local

            // ...
        }

        await _repo.SaveChangesAsync();
 
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Repo {
    private DbContext _ctx;

    public Repo(DbContext ctx) {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
    
    public T Insert<T>(T e) where T : class {
        _ctx.Add(e); 
        return e;
    }

    public IQueryable<TObject> AllIncluding<TObject>(params Expression<Func<TObject, object>>[] includeProperties) where TObject : class {
        IQueryable<TObject> query = _ctx.Set<TObject>();
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => {                
            return current.Include(includeProperty);
        });
    }

    public IEnumerable<TObject> InCache<TObject>() where TObject : class {
        return _ctx.Set<TObject>().Local;
    }

    public T GetByCache<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> w) {
        T e = InCache<T>().Where(w.Compile()).FirstOrDefault();  // Exception raised from here

        if (e == null)
            e = AllIncluding<T>(includeProperties).Where(w).FirstOrDefault();

        return e;
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync() {
        return _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

right now I solve the problem by rewriting the InCache function as follows:

```cs
public IEnumerable<TObject> InCache<TObject>() where TObject : class {
    return _ctx.Set<TObject>().Local.ToList();
}
```

This makes me feel really uncomfortable.

Comment: What is `CollectionOfModels`?

Comment: You can't edit a collection while enumerating it. Without the definition of `CollectionOfModels`, my guess is `Insert` modifies it.

Comment: @GertArnold I edited the question. It is an IEnumerable of ModelType

Comment: @YungDeiza yes but when I `Insert` I'm no longer in the enumeration. The scope of the enumeration is `GetByCache`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A DbSet isn't a table or collection, it represents an Entity Type in the Unit-of-Work, ie the DbContext. That means the DbContext itself goes away once the "business transaction" completes so *caching* at the DbSet level doesn't make a lot of sense. Individual object are already cached by the UoW ie DbContext

Comment: The error makes perfect sense by the way. `Local` is a view of the tracked entities, which *do* change all the time. If you iterate over it while it's being modified then yes, you'll get errors. The code you posted *does* modify it by calling `Add` while iterating over it to find the first item with `GetByCache`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i add more "context". I do not think modifying Local during a loop over Local, and vice et versa.

Comment: @tschmit007 Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It works fine in a test environment, but you might have a different environment/situation than posted in the question. Not to mention that you code has compile errors...

Comment: @tschmit007 you aren't modifying `Local`, you're modifying what Local exposes - the tracked entities. The extra info makes it even harder to understand the point of the code - unless you changed the DbContext registration from Scope to Singleton, a major problem. When a DbContext exists only for a single action, there's not much point to a GetByCache - the object isn't there when the action starts anyway.

Comment: @tschmit007 are you trying to deduplicate the contents of `CollectionOfModels`? Why not write a LINQ query that only returns unique objects then? Your code isn't inserting anything to the database until `SaveChanges` is called so there's no reason to ask the DbContext if an object exists or not. If you want all objects, `DbContext.AddRange(CollectionOfModels)` is enough. If you only want eg the first object by ID, `var firsts=var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => x.First()); context.AddRange(firsts);`

Comment: If you really want to cache objects between controller actions you'll have to use a separate cache *outside* DbContext. The context itself doesn't survive the action.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is not between, it is inside the controller action. And the context is scoped to the query lifetime. Everything happens during one query.

Comment: In that case what's the point of `GetByCache`? Unless there are objects with duplicate IDs,  why not add all new objects you with eg `AddRange` or `UpdateRange`? The objects cached by a DbContext are those you already loaded or attached so there's no reason to ask the *Context* for them - you already have them somewhere.

Comment: The Upsert method is `Update`, but only for detached objects. Objects with PK values will be tracked as `Modified`, objects without will be tracked as `Added`. Tracked objects need nothing - EF will detect any changes made to them automatically. You can simplify your code a lot by handling loaded and new objects separately. If `CollectionOfModels` contains only new objects, there's no need to check if they exist

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the goal is to link slave(s) to a master. If the slave does not exist then is inserted. That's why I check Local to know if current slave allready exists (in any state (added, non modified...)) otherwise I hit the db to see if it exists. May be my "design" is wrong

Comment: You aren't checking if it doesn't exist though, but if you loaded it earlier. That object should be in a variable or collection in the controller or action. You never "hit the db", at least not in this code. What you described is performed by `Find` already - if an object with those primary key values exists in cache, it's returned. Otherwise a database query is executed. You could write `Entity?  e=context.Find<T>(m.Id)` or `Entity? e=context.MySet.Find(m.Id)`.

Comment: I do two successive checks/queries from : 1) Set().Local and if it fails 2) Set() (this one should update Local by loading the entity). I can't use Find because the check isn't related to the PK. (if I had .ToList() after Local it just works like a charm)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos btw, outside an ApisControlller method, this code runs.

Comment: BTW [Local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.local?view=efcore-7.0) is a LocalView object, not an ObservableCollection and can't be used for binding without conversion. This code is very unusual and *definitely* not necessary. Even the fact that ID isn't the primary key is unusual

Comment: At the very least post something that other people can compile to reproduce your problem. Right now the question depends on a lot of code and assumptions that only exist on your machine. Why don't you know if the items are already loaded for example? What happened to the objects that were loaded previously? One could *assume* that `CollectionOfModels` contains only detached models that came from a request, and some of those are copies of objects that were loaded previously. Why not filter the copies out of the collection then?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm working on a compilable sample right now. (think i will ask a new question)