# DbSet.Local raises Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is a following of a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016513/dbset-local-is-raising-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-ex) with **asked compilable code**.

- First the throwing code,
- Seconde the csproj file,
- Third exception infos,
- then the fixes I found.

My question remains: why does this code raise an exception?

The goal of this code is: from a list of "code"s received from a thirdparty set relations between a Master entity and Slave entities corresponding to the received code. If a slave entity does not exist, then it is created.

This code focus on the case where the Slave entities allready exists. Please be aware that the set relation has some additional properties.

Please don't start by telling me that there are better patterns to acheive this goal (I'm sure there is). I'm seraching for the resaon why the exception is thrown.

- I updated my projet to efcore 7.0.10.
- this code does not commit anything
- you will need `EntityFrameworkCore` and `EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` packages.
- I used SqlServer Express Edition

```csharp
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

using (TestContext cctx = new TestContext()) {
    cctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
}


using (TestContext ctx = new TestContext()) {
    Repo inc = new Repo(ctx);
    int masterId = 1;
    Master? m = await inc.AllIncluding<Master>().Where(x => x.Id == masterId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    foreach (string code in new List<string> { "X", "Y" }) {        
        MasterTMClass? dbe = await inc.AllIncluding<MasterTMClass>().
            Where(x => x.MasterId == masterId && x.Class.Classification.Name == "ABC" && x.Class.Code == code).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (dbe == null) {
            // ===========================================================
            TMClass? s = inc.GetSingleByCache<TMClass>(
                x => x.Classification.Name == "ABC" && x.Code == code);  //Exception here when seeking for code == "Y"
            // ===========================================================
            dbe = new MasterTMClass();
            dbe.MasterId = masterId;
            dbe.Class = s;
            dbe.Description = "";
            inc.Insert(dbe);
        } 
        dbe.Description += "+";
    }
}

public class Master {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<MasterTMClass> Slaves { get; set; }
}

public class Classification {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TMClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClassificationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Classification Classification { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class MasterTMClass {
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual TMClass Class { get; set; }
    public Int16? Seq { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Classification> Classifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TMClass> TMClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MasterTMClass> MastersTMClasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        optionsBuilder.
            UseLazyLoadingProxies().
            UseSqlServer(
                //@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestLocal;Trusted_Connection=True"
                @"Server=localhost\SQL140EXP;Database=TestLocal;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False"
        );
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MasterTMClass>().HasKey( x => new { x.MasterId, x.ClassId } );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().HasData(new Master {
            Id = 1
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Classification>().HasData(new Classification {
            Id = 1, Name = "ABC"
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TMClass>().HasData(new TMClass {
            Id = 1, ClassificationId = 1, Code = "X"
        }, new TMClass {
            Id = 2, ClassificationId = 1, Code = "Y"
        });
    }
}

public class Repo {
    private DbContext _ctx;

    public Repo(DbContext ctx) {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

    public T Insert<T>(T e) where T : class {
        _ctx.Add(e);
        return e;
    }

    public IQueryable<TObject> AllIncluding<TObject>(params Expression<Func<TObject, object>>[] includeProperties) where TObject : class {
        IQueryable<TObject> query = _ctx.Set<TObject>();
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => {
            return current.Include(includeProperty);
        });
    }

    public IEnumerable<TObject> InCache<TObject>() where TObject : class {
        return _ctx.Set<TObject>().Local;
    }

    public T? GetByCache<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> w, bool single = false, params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] includeProperties) where T : class {
        //========================================================================
        T? e = InCache<T>().Where(w.Compile()).FirstOrDefault(); // Exception here
        //========================================================================

        if (e == null)
            if (single)
                e = AllIncluding<T>(includeProperties).Where(w).SingleOrDefault();
            else
                e = AllIncluding<T>(includeProperties).Where(w).FirstOrDefault();

        return e;
    }

    public T? GetSingleByCache<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> w) where T : class {
        return GetByCache(w, true);
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync() {
        await  _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.10" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Raised exception is:

> System.InvalidOperationException : 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

The call stack:

```
[Code externe]  
SetLocal.dll!Repo.GetByCache<TMClass>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TMClass, bool>> w, bool single, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TMClass, object>>[] includeProperties) Ligne 120    C#
SetLocal.dll!Repo.GetSingleByCache<TMClass>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TMClass, bool>> w) Ligne 132 C#
SetLocal.dll!Program.<Main>$(string[] args) Ligne 18    C#
[Code externe]
```

I found two solutions.

First:

```csharp
    public IEnumerable<TObject> InCache<TObject>() where TObject : class {
        return _ctx.Set<TObject>().Local.ToList();
    }
```

Second, found by looking in ctx.ChangeTraker.DebugView.ShortView revealing that at some point a Classification Entity is loaded without reason. So I give up querying by name and use a specific query to get an id from the db:

```csharp
using (TestContext ctx = new TestContext()) {
    Repo inc = new Repo(ctx);
    int masterId = 1;
    int classifId = inc.AllIncluding<Classification>().
        Where(x => x.Name == "ABC").Select(x => x.Id).SingleAsync(); // specific query
    Master? m = await inc.AllIncluding<Master>().Where(x => x.Id == masterId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    foreach (string code in new List<string> { "X", "Y" }) {        
        MasterTMClass? dbe = await inc.AllIncluding<MasterTMClass>().
            Where(x => x.MasterId == masterId && x.Class.ClassificationId == classifId && x.Class.Code == code).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        // ------------------------------------------------------------^
        if (dbe == null) {
            TMClass? s = inc.GetSingleByCache<TMClass>(x => x.ClassificationId == classifId && x.Code == code);
            // -------------------------------------------------------------^
            dbe = new MasterTMClass();
            dbe.MasterId = masterId;
            dbe.Class = s;
            dbe.Description = "";
            inc.Insert(dbe);
        } 
        dbe.Description += "+";
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because `inc.GetSingleByCache` do not include `Classification`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you probably got something: Local is local, and with LazyLoading enabled using it may trigger loadings. (but it does not explain why Local.ToList() fixes the problem)

Comment: @JohnLBevan sorry, this is a following of a previous post, I added data about the exception.

Comment: It does explain. Lazy loading modifies Local collection. So, in your filer you have `x. Classification` lazy loading trigger which explains why enumeration is being modified. If you analyse stack trace you should see that.